# Number of unicycles on vertex set $[n]$

Tags: graph-theory

Given that a unicycle is a simple graph with only one cycle, and let $u_n$ be the number of unicycles on vertex set $[n]$. How do I find a formula for $u_n$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $G$ is a unicycle on $[n]$. Let $C$ be the cycle of $G$, and suppose that $C$ is a $k$-cycle. Removing the edges of $C$ leaves a forest of $k$ rooted trees, the roots being the vertices in $C$. The number of rooted forests on $[n]$ with a specified set of $k$ roots is $kn^{n-k-1}$; the formula can be found at [OEIS A$232006$](http://oeis.org/A232006), and a straightforward proof can be found in the last section of [this PDF](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2006/PAPERS/Casarotto.pdf). Now combine this with the number of ways to choose the $k$ roots and arrange them in a $k$-cycle and sum over $k$ to get a formula for $u_n$. (If this is the exercise in Bóna, you’re allowed one summation.)